# How can I append an int to a tchar?

Tags: c++, c, string, formatting

For testing purposes I would like each time I create a file name to add a number to it - the app I am testing has no user interface, and will likely create multiple files.

```
void somefunction()
{
    static INT iFileNo = 0;
    TCHAR tFileName[MAX_PATH] = L"c:/test/abcd.bmp";
    iFileNo ++;
}
```

I would like to somehow append the `iFileNo` to the `tFileName` (to get something like `abcd1.bmp`, `abcd2.bmp`...)... How can I do that ?

Note: I am not using any string libraries

Minimal libraries... including

```
#include <STDLIB.H>
#include <STDIO.H>
#include <TCHAR.H>
```

Intended OS: Windows

Comment: You're using `TCHAR` but prefixing the string with `L` which will always give you a wide string. If you always want a wide string then just use `wchar_t`

Comment: Thanks, calling CreateFileW which takes LPCWSTR argument for file name, I will fix that... I am still experimenting and learning this character stuff... not sure what LPCWSTR needs but the TCHAR and wchar_t both worked :-)

Comment: `TCHAR` is a macro, it's either defined as `char` or `wchar_t` depending on your compiler settings.

Comment: After your edit the question is 'C' but not 'C++' any more.

Comment: Does not have to be pure C... but the libraries ae minimal, because of its intended use

Comment: @Thalia: what's the intended use, if you can't even use std::string? I'm not familiar with much systems where I want to process file names, deal with strings, use C++, but would not use C++ standard library. That just seems so arbitrary...

Comment: I am figuring out how to create a plugin for a printer driver... Modifying the Microsoft samples to get a specific use... And I think it is best not to include any libraries that are not already used in the WDK sample, adding more will just make it bulkier ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make this hard, easy, or very easy. The middle of those would be something like:

```
void somefunction()
{
    static unsigned int uiFileNo = 0;
    static const WCHAR wSpec[] = L"c:/test/abcd%u.bmp";

    WCHAR wFileName[MAX_PATH];    
    swprintf_s(wFileName, MAX_PATH, wSpec, uiFileNo++);
}
```

Uses [**`swprintf_s`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce3zzk1k(v=vs.110).aspx), which would seem to fulfill your include-file restrictions (and assuming this is Windows, which your question seems to indicate).

Personally I's use `std::wstring`, but it appears you have reasons against it. Anyway, best of luck.

Comment: Yes - I should have mentioned the OS, it is strictly Windows, thank you for the very nice example

Comment: @Thalia consider what James said as well If you want lexicographically comparable filenames, changes the format spec to use something like `abcd%.4u.bmp`, which will `'0'`-fill the number, `0000`, `0001`, etc, giving you 10000 numbers before bleeding in to a 5th digit place.

Comment: I was just looking at that, it is a great point (since I really am only outputting debug files I didn't really care but I may as well make it look professional). Thank you so much

Comment: @WhozCraig Just curious, but why `%.4u`, rather than `%04u`?  (In my experience, a lot of people don't know how precision works with integral types, where as many more seem to understand `%04u`.)

Comment: @JamesKanze I dunno. Its just a preference thing, a switchover from a number of years ago. I concur most people either don't understand or know about it (but maybe they may now =)

Comment: @WhozCraig It just struck me because I've never seen it actually used before.  (I know about it because I've actually implemented `printf` in a C library, something like 25 years ago.)  Also: there is no equivalent in iostream: the `precision` is ignored when outputting ints.  This caused me no end of problems when I tried to implement `Format`, for C style formatting on an `ostream`.  (The `boost::format` takes a pragmatic approach, and doesn't support it either.  My pre-Boost implementation was a challenge from a collegue to make it 100% compatible.)

Answer (score 2):

You've expressed a desire to not use *any* libraries. That's not a choice I would endorse, but since you asked...

The easiest way would be to decide on a fixed number of digits, with leading zeros. That makes the problem trivial. In this example I'm using two digits.

```
void somefunction()
{
    static INT iFileNo = 0;
    TCHAR tFileName[MAX_PATH] = L"c:/test/abcd00.bmp";
    int iNumberOffset = 12;
    if (iFileNo >= 100)
        throw std::runtime_error("File number too large");
    tFileName[iNumberOffset] += iFileNo / 10;
    tFileName[iNumberOffset+1] += iFileNo % 10;
    iFileNo ++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the example and comments

Comment: And you initialize the string each time.  I'd missed that.  (And the way you're doing it probably works for `wchar_t` as well.)  I've deleted my comment, since it isn't really relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ostringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/ostringstream/):

```
std::ostringstream s;
s << "c:/test/abcd.bmp"
s << iFileNo++;

std::string filename = s.str();
```

If you want wide versions (as you're specifying `L` in your example) then use `wstringstream` and `wstring`.

If you really don't want to use a C++ library then you can use [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/):

```
char filename[100];
sprint(filename, "c:/test/abcd.tmp-%d", iFileNo);
iFileNo++
```

You'll need to ensure that you buffer is big enough to hold the filename.

If you really don't want to use any libraries then Windows actually has it's own string formatting function, [wsprintf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647550%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which you can use instead of `sprintf`.

Comment: It should be `std::ostringstream`.  Other than that: in cases like this, I've found it useful to set `fill` to `'0'` and to use a width; it means that a lexicographical sort on the file names will return them in order.  (But if they're totally unrelated files, this is probably irrelevant.)

Comment: Thank you very much, the std::string version will also help me in other places